# How to set Stripe Subscription's billing cycle date to 1st of every month?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I need to set subscription billing to 1st of every month in stripe. I have followed doc https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/billing-cycle, but not exactly cleared how to set it for per month.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Thank you for your question, we always like to help. However, I think that we need a little more information in order to answer it. Maybe you can include some code samples of what you've done already? We always encourage people to create well-researched questions.

Answer (score 2):

For Stripe Subscriptions to bill on the 1st of every month you need to do the following:

1. Use a recurring Price that bills monthly
2. Set `billing_cycle_anchor` to a timestamp on the 1st of the month

From the documentation you linked to in your question:

> For example, a customer with a monthly subscription set to cycle on the 2nd of the month will always be billed on the 2nd.

So it sounds like you're on the right track!